# Left Join postgres SQL duplicate ON column

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, left-join

I am doing a LEFT JOIN on a postgres table. As a result, in my final table appears a duplicate column, which is the column ON I have done the join. Why?

```
select *
from ltc_ts lt 
left join ltc_stock_metrics lsm 
on lt."index" =lsm."index"
```

PS: "index" is a column name for both tables I want to join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended solution is to **not** use `select *` but only select those columns that you really need.

If you want to stick with `select *` you can join with the `using()` clause instead. This will then return the `index` column only once.

```
select *
from ltc_ts lt 
  left join ltc_stock_metrics lsm using ("index")
```